# Ghost control input

Tags: pc, windows-7, keyboard, splinter-cell-chaos-theory

I'm trying to play Splinter Cell 3 CT on Windows 7 x64.
When ingame there are "ghost" control inputs not made by me that cause the character to move on its own. In one observed case it even caused a weapon draw without any input from me.

I thought this might be related to FPS issues so I capped it at 30 but to no avail. Tried several different resolutions as well without any changes to the ghost input behavior. Unplugging the keyboard does not change anything either.

Is there anyone who has experienced this issue before and knows how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to see if this happens on other games?

Comment: Do you have a controller plugged in?

Comment: Nope, sorry... I played it last year on Win10 without issue.